# "String of nat" in Isabelle?

Tags: isabelle

I'm struggling to find a function of type `nat => string` that converts terms like

```
42
```

into terms like

```
''42''
```

Does it exist? I've found `char_of_nat` (in the [String](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/library/HOL/HOL/String.html) library) but that's a bit too low-level, being concerned with ASCII codes and the like.

Answer (score 2):

In the archive of formal proofs, under `Real_Impl/Show` you find a class `show` with a function essentially of type `'a => string`. In `Real_Impl/Show_Instances` several common types are instantiated, including `nat`, `rat`, and `int`.

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, I've gone ahead and written my own `string_of_nat` and `string_of_int` functions. In the absence of other pre-existing functions, these will suit me fine.

```
fun string_of_nat :: "nat ⇒ string"
where
  "string_of_nat n = (if n < 10 then [char_of_nat (48 + n)] else 
     string_of_nat (n div 10) @ [char_of_nat (48 + (n mod 10))])"

definition string_of_int :: "int ⇒ string"
where
  "string_of_int i = (if i < 0 then ''-'' @ string_of_nat (nat (- i)) else 
     string_of_nat (nat i))"
```

Comment: There is also the `show` class of [IsaFoR](http://afp.sourceforge.net/browser_info/current/AFP/Real_Impl/Show.html) (which currently, for technical reasons is part of the AFP entry `Real_Impl`) whose purpose is to turn values of arbitrary type into strings and comes with instances for basic types like `nat`, `int`, `'a list`, .... In the near future this will be turned into a separate AFP entry, since it might be of general interest.

Answer (score 1):

There's a Haskell-like `show` class in the [AFP entry *Show*](https://www.isa-afp.org/entries/Show.html).

The instance for the `nat` type is in `Show.Show_Instances`.

---

**Example**:

```
theory Show_Test
    imports "Show.Show_Instances" 
begin


lemma "show (123 :: nat) = ''123''" 
  by (simp add: Show_Instances.shows_prec_nat_def showsp_nat.simps shows_string_def) 


end
```